# Fabric run command on different hosts simultaneously

Tags: python, fabric

I'm using fabric and I want to download a file simultaneously on different hosts at the same time but when I use

`env.hosts = ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']`

I always get `No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:`

```
from fabric.api import env ,  run, sudo, settings
env.user = 'root' #all the servers have the same username
env.hosts = ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.4']
env.key_filename = "~/.ssh/id_rsa" # I have their ssh key
run('wget file') #The command I need to run in parrallel
```

I want to run this from a python code without using the fab command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the @parallel decorator (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/parallel.html) and do something like this.

```
env.use_ssh_config = True
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.sudo_user = 'ubuntu'
env.roledefs = {
    'uat': ['website_uat'],
    'prod': ['website01', 'website02']
}

@task
def deploy(role_from_arg, **kwargs):
    # on each remote download file
    execute(download_file, role=role_from_arg, **kwargs)


@parallel
def download_file(*args, **kwargs):
    # some code to download file here
```

Then i can run `fab deploy:prod`

Comment: Thanks it helped me I used env.hosts instead of env.roledefs and I ran deploy() in my code without the fab command. and it worked like magic.

Comment: What does `:prod` do?

Comment: @slimtabka : Can you post your code (the one that worked for you)?

Comment: Hi I'm really sorry I don't have access to he code anymore it was with my previous job, as for :prod I don't know what it does because I used fabric from python directely and not with fab command!

Comment: @pg2455 the prod is to say run the task deploy but use the roledef called prod which lists 2 servers. So this means it will connect to website01 and run download_file and then connect to website02 and run download_file.